How to export labels with callout/leader from ArcGIS to CAD (Microstation)?
I need to export labels with leader/callout from ArcGIS Pro to CAD (Microstation).
First I Convert Labels To Annotations and then use Export To CAD and attach the CAD file in Microstation. This works, however, this only shows the label text. I want leader/callout with the labels.
Is there any way to export labels with leaders/callout from ArcGIS to CAD (Microstation)?
